# Find all combinations of the numbers in a vector. R programming

Tags: r

Are there any direct functions that can be used to get the combinations of all the items in the vector?

```
myVector <- c(1,2,3)
for (i in myVector)
    for (j in myVector)
        for (k in myVector)
            print(paste(i,j,k,sep=","))
```

The screenshot of the first part of the output look like this. As there are three values 1,2,3 there will be

> 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 lines

[image]

I tried to get the permutations using the function permn() as,

> permn(myVector)

But is giving only the 9 different values.
Screenshot of the output :

[image]

Is there any direct function that can produce such a result as shown in the first?

Comment: Side note: my package `vecsets`  will perform intersections, unions, etc. on vectors with repeated elements as you describe here.

Answer (score 3):

Using `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral`.

```
r <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(myVector, length(myVector), repetition=TRUE)
head(r, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    2
# [3,]    1    1    3
```

If you want the comma separated strings, do

```
apply(r, 1, paste, collapse=",")
# [1] "1,1,1" "1,1,2" "1,1,3" "1,2,1" "1,2,2" "1,2,3" "1,3,1"
# [8] "1,3,2" "1,3,3" "2,1,1" "2,1,2" "2,1,3" "2,2,1" "2,2,2"
# [15] "2,2,3" "2,3,1" "2,3,2" "2,3,3" "3,1,1" "3,1,2" "3,1,3"
# [22] "3,2,1" "3,2,2" "3,2,3" "3,3,1" "3,3,2" "3,3,3"
```

Or the list output, you've also shown

```
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(myVector, length(myVector), FUN=function(x) 
  paste(x, collapse=","), repetition=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "1,1,1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1,1,2"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "1,1,3"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "1,2,1"
# ...
```

You may decide on your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `expand.grid` :

```
tmp <- expand.grid(myVector, myVector, myVector)
tmp

#   Var1 Var2 Var3
#1     1    1    1
#2     2    1    1
#3     3    1    1
#4     1    2    1
#5     2    2    1
#6     3    2    1
#...
#...
```

If you want to do this automatically for the length of `myVector` without manually specifying it 3 times you can use `replicate`.

```
tmp <- do.call(expand.grid, replicate(length(myVector),
               myVector, simplify = FALSE))
```

To paste the values together you can do :

```
do.call(paste, c(tmp, sep = ','))

# [1] "1,1,1" "2,1,1" "3,1,1" "1,2,1" "2,2,1" "3,2,1" "1,3,1" "2,3,1"
# [9] "3,3,1" "1,1,2" "2,1,2" "3,1,2" "1,2,2" "2,2,2" "3,2,2" "1,3,2"
#[17] "2,3,2" "3,3,2" "1,1,3" "2,1,3" "3,1,3" "1,2,3" "2,2,3" "3,2,3"
#[25] "1,3,3" "2,3,3" "3,3,3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a `permutations` function in the `gtools` package that allows you to generalize permutation outputs:

```
library(gtools)
permutations(3, 3, 1:3, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    2
 [3,]    1    1    3
 [4,]    1    2    1
 [5,]    1    2    2
 [6,]    1    2    3
 [7,]    1    3    1
 [8,]    1    3    2
 [9,]    1    3    3
[10,]    2    1    1
```

The function help describes the parameter settings.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `pracma::combs`  does exactly this.  That, and `pracma::perms` generate output sets which treat every element of the input as distinct, regardless of whether a value is repeated.